# Content security Policy - Refused to load the script from google analytics - CSP rules correct

Tags: jquery, symfony, google-analytics, inline, content-security-policy

I have a issue when setting CSP rules on server.

In the server , I set: **Header Content-Security-Policy to:**

`default-src 'self';script-src 'self' 'report-sample' www.google-analytics.com`

When refresh browser , I got :
[image]

When check the js source  , it's the library jquery.

How I can fix it ?
Thanks

config csp :
[image]

Error on browser
[image]

Comment: try to add `https://` to `www.google-analytics.com` in your rule

Comment: @Kosh . Same error

Comment: It's fine to set in the header, or meta tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Comment: @Jonathan , I have tryed this that nothing to change

Comment: the error in browser shows 'report-sample' but the header doesn't include that. also, remove the space after .com, before the ; and, for the heck of it, retype the whole string `https://www.google-analytics.com` to make sure there's nothing weird in there.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things.

The answer is in the error message. It says the violation is from `script-src`.

It prints the script-src's value as it parsed it, and doesn't include `www.google-analytics.com` when it prints the value.

So - take out the 'report-sample' and see what changes.

Next, looking at the [syntax for the script-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src), it requires a scheme or port number. replace the host with the `https://www.googleanalytics.com`.

Googling for csp and google-analytics comes back with a few results - this is the one from [google support resource](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/web/csp#universal_analytics_google_analytics):

It's not limited to google-analytics, but might help get the right URIs in the CSP policy.

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src: https://www.google-analytics.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com; img-src: https://www.google-analytics.com
connect-src: https://www.google-analytics.com
```

If you're still having problems, show us a sample of the headers form the developer tools, network tab.

Comment: Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';script-src  'self' https://www.google-analytics.com ;style-src 'report-sample' 'self' 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=' 'sha256-/PVkO2+mUlKqE6wgKVXU5Wh4mx3vncHAxLEdpXrziGo=' ;object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';connect-src 'self';font-src fonts.gstatic.com 'self';frame-src 'self';img-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com data:;manifest-src 'self';media-src 'self';report-uri https://5f3f65f2b641482c3e7cf5ab.endpoint.csper.io/;worker-src 'none';

Comment: add that to your question. add 'https://' to the google urls and try again. put the new error message on the question as well.

Comment: Same issue with the directive  style-src using hash